# What happens to a Celery Worker's scheduled (eta) tasks when it shuts down?

Tags: python, celery

I've been learning about celery and haven't been able to find the answer to a conceptual question and have had odd results experimenting.

When there are scheduled tasks (by scheduled, I don't mean periodic but scheduled to run in the future using eta=x) submitted to Celery, they seem to be consumed from the queue by a worker right away (rather than staying in the Redis default celery key/queue). Presumably, the worker will actually execute the tasks at eta.

What happens if that worker were to be shut down or restarted (to update it's registered tasks for example)? Would those scheduled tasks be lost? They are not "running" so a warm terminate wouldn't wait for them to finish of course.

Is there a way to force those tasks to be return to the queue and consumed by the next available worker?

I suppose, manually, one could dump the tasks before shutting down a worker:

http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#inspecting-workers

and resubmit them when a new worker is back up... but is this supposed to happen automatically?

Would really appreciate any help with this

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at acks_late
http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.acks_late

If set to true Celery will keep the task in the queue until it has been successfully executed.

Comment: Just to clarify, this means that if a task has been set to execute in two hours (e.g. eta = 2hrs from now) then it will remain in the queue and be consumed only at the point of execution?

Comment: A worker will grab the task, but not execute it until the ETA. Should the worker die, the task will return to the queue as it only ACKs when completed.

Answer (score 1):

**Update: Celery 5.1**

Workers will acknowledge the message even if `acks_late` is enabled. This is the default and intentional setting set forth by the library. [[Ref](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/tasks.html#tasks)]

To change the default settings and re-queue your unfinished tasks, you can use the `task_reject_on_worker_lost` config. [[Ref](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#task-reject-on-worker-lost)]

Although keep in mind that this could lead to a message loop and can cause unintended effects if your tasks are not *idempotent*.

Specifically for *eta tasks*, queues wait for workers to acknowledge the tasks before deleting them. With default settings, celery workers ack right before the task is executed and with `acks_late` when the task is finished executing.

So when workers fail to ack the tasks probably because of shutdown/restart/lost_connection or in case of Redis/SQS `visibility_timeout` exceeded [[ref](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/glossary.html?highlight=visibility%20timeout#term-acknowledged)], the queue will redeliver the message to any available worker.